# Given `() => IO[T]`, can I obtain `IO[() => T]`?

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I have an object

```scala
    object Producer {
      def apply() :IO[Foo] = ???
    }
```

It is in code I do not control. I am composing (flat mapping) several functions returning `IO`. One of them hides a `Ref`, and exposes `update` method compatible with it:

```scala
    object State {
      def update(update: Bar => Bar) :IO[Bar] = ???
    }
```

This one I do control, although introducing significant changes would cause a large refactor.

Problem:

```scala
    for {
      bar <- State.update { arg => ??? }
    } yield ()
```

In some cases, but not all, I need a `Foo` to produce a new `Bar` inside the lambda passed to `State.update`.
Can it be done without always evaluating `foo <- Producer` as the first step?

Comment: I am unable to understand what is the problem / question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of thinking of `IO[A]` is that it is `() => A` (or `() => Future[A]`).

So `() => IO[T]` and `IO[() => T]` are kinda the same idea, just with a different *ergonomics* (and different ways of evaluating what's inside). So you should be able to go from one into another and back e.g. with:

```scala
val a: () => IO[A] = ...
val b: IO[() => A] = IO { () => a.runUnsafeSync }

val c: IO[() => A] = ...
val d: () => IO[A] = () => c.map(_())
```

However, the devil is in the details:

- such `runUnsafeSync` will not propagate cancellation from the outer IO to the inner IO
- similarly it would not propagate state update in `IOLocal`

so making a bullet-proof conversion this way would be... rather difficult.

And hardly ever it would be useful as with ergonomics there comes a convention:

- `IO[A]` suggest a side-effect (or at least a possibility of it)
- `X => non-IO` suggest pure computation - take `X`, then return sth without mutation nor talking to external world
- `() =>` provides no new information, so such pure function would have to be constant (it might be a lazy value basically)

so if we followed the convention, we could convert `fa: () => IO[A]` into `IO[() => A]` by doing

```scala
IO.defer {
  fa()
}.map { a =>
  // a is a constant value, so function we created is constant
  // and everything that obtains it through e.g. map/flatMap
  // would get the same value no matter how many times it would be called.

  // However, evaluation whole IO twice could result in 2 functions
  // returning different constant values.
  () => a
}
```

It should make the conversion trivial, but it would also mean that all these `() =>` in the context of `IO[A]` are kinda pointless. Unless you need to do them to adapt your code to some external interface which expects `() => F[A]` or `F[() => A]`, it's just noise.

Comment: `IO { () => a.runUnsafeSync }`... well, if you allow yourself to `runUnsafeSync` all the `IO`s, `Await` all the `Future`s, and `.get` all the `Option`s, you can always pretty much go from anything to anything, isn't this kind-of missing the entire point?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: can we go from `A => IO[B]` to `IO[A => B]`. Think of it conceptually.

Let's say that we have a function `String => IO[Int]` that takes a username, reads the user data from a database, and returns the user's age (wrapped in `IO` because we have a database call). You are then looking for a higher-order function that can turn that name -> age function into a single effectful value `IO[String => Int]`. How could that possibly work? What could the implementation of `String => Int` be? Neither one of the following two things exists:

- database lookup using a function instead of username
- some other implementation that can obtain the age purely, without doing the database lookup

Those are two completely different things. Here's a hint on their difference:

- Monad's `flatMap` takes a function of type `A => F[B]`, or in your case `A => IO[B]`.
- Applicative functor's `apply` takes a function of type `F[A => B]`, or in your case `IO[A => B]`.
- Applicative is the weaker (= more general) abstraction.

Using a for-comp like you suggest is the right way.

```
for {
  producedBar <- Producer.apply
  bar <- State.update { arg => producedBar }
} yield ()
```

or written differently

```
Producer.apply().flatMap(producedBar => State.update(arg => producedBar))
```

It clearly shows that doing a state update depends on another function that dictates the new updated value. Or in case of our earlier example - it shows that you need to obtain your number first, before you can apply your "triple" function to it.

Note that this only speaks about the *order* or *dependency chain* of operations. It says nothing about their actual execution in the real world; we're only describing the algorithm for our lazy side-effectful program. (unlike using e.g. eagerly evaluated `Future`, in which case your concerns would be much more justified)

Can you explain what's problematic about this?